# SQLite3 in CodeIgniter 3.0.6

Tags: php, codeigniter, sqlite

I can't find any documentation on how to use sqlite3 in CodeIgniter, but it does say that it is supported.

Here is my current database configuration:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db/base.db';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlite3';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

But I get a very undescriptive error on page load

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 500
```

So my question is, why is my config not working, and how can I make it work?

Comment: That looks like the Ci2 database lay out http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using CI2 syntax, I don't know where you got it as in default package you can find the same code as below, where only thing you need to define is `database` (path to db) and `dbdriver`

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'      => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => './application/database/data.db',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlite3',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt'  => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Or you can use this (with *PDO* database driver which requires dsn string, otherwise CI will try to build it)

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'      => 'sqlite:application/database/data.db',// path/to/database
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt'  => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'database' => './application/database/data.db',
```

if not working replace with

```
'database' => APPPATH.'database/data.db',
```

and

```
'dsn'      => 'sqlite:application/database/data.db',// path/to/database
```

if not working replace with

```
'dsn'      => 'sqlite:'.APPPATH.'/database/data.db',// path/to/database
```